# Unable to save file changes while using VS Code Remote Container due to "read-only file system"

Tags: vscode-remote

I'm experimenting with using dev-containers for development by trying to follow along with this simple example: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python

The setup works fine and I am able to build and connect to the container, and run the app just fine. However, if I try to edit anything and save it, I get an error:

```
Failed to save 'app.py': Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://dev-container+2f55736572732f62726164656e2e6b696e6172642f706572736f6e616c2f7673636f64652d72656d6f74652d7472792d707974686f6e/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-python/app.py' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-python/app.py')
```

If I open a secondary window with the local folder open, I can save changes and those are reflected in the remote container window. But due to the file system being set to read-only, I can't edit anything from within the remote container. Any ideas on why I am stuck in read-only?

One potentially important note is that I am using using Colima (version 0.2.2) rather than Docker Desktop, thought I haven't found anything to indicate that this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own problem. Turns out the issue was using Colima as a runtime. I came across the discussion around [issue #102 on the Colima Github page](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/issues/102). According to the developer, the default mount "Used to be read-only, but changed to writable in version 0.3.0.". I was using v0.2.2.

I updated colima to the most recent version (v0.4.4) and it fixed the issue for me.